# react-select: How do I resolve “Warning: Prop `id` did not match”

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-select

I have a web app with ReactJs and NextJs. In a functional component, I have used **react-select** then, I'm receiving the following console warning:

> Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server: "react-select-7-input" Client: "react-select-2-input"

My code is the following:

```
import { Row, Col, Card, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Select from 'react-select';

const priorityOptions = [
  { value: 'p1', label: 'Top level - P1' },
  { value: 'p2', label: 'Mid level - P2' },
  { value: 'p3', label: 'Low level - P3' }
];
const PostView = () => {
  return (
    <div className="DashboardSla-ContentBody__Form">
      <Row>
        <Col md="10">
          <Card className="shadow-sm">
            <Card.Body>
              <Form>
                <h5 className="text-secondary mb-3">Booking details</h5>
                <Form.Group controlId="postType">
                  <Form.Label>Booking priority</Form.Label>
                  <Select 
                    id="postType"
                    placeholder="Make a selection"
                    options={priorityOptions}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="primary"
                >Add Booking</Button>
              </Form>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostView;
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the `instanceId`? See here: https://react-select.com/props and https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2629

Comment: I have replaced `id="postType"` as `instanceId="postType"`. Still showing error in console.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I think it has something to do with rehydration of an SSR React app but not sure how to solve that.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

try to add prop `instanceId` set as unique string and should work

Comment: tested on react-select using Next.js, it works no more warning. Thanks!

Comment: I'm working with Next.js an with react-select and it works to me, thanks.

Comment: Hey, I've just tested it and it works! Thanks!

Comment: FYI - capitalisation counts. I couldn't twig to this until I finally realised i had instanceid not instanceId

Comment: FYI - if you are getting this error working with next.js and "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome", the property to use is titleId.

Comment: Thanks man, I finally got rid of the warning

Comment: Where did i go wrong? Setting `instanceId` helped to get rid of `id` prop warning. But now I have similar issue: `Warning: Prop \`className\` did not match`

Comment: still works with nextjs app router

Comment: worked for me today with nextjs: 13.5.6 and react-select: 5.8.0

Answer (score 35):

React 18 introduces a `useId` hook for generating an ID that is hydration-safe (stable across client and server renders) but still globally unique. You can use it to solve this problem. I use the following component in place of `Select`:

```
import React, { useId } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default function StableSelect({ ...props }) {
  return <Select {...props} instanceId={useId()} />;
}
```

You can use this component exactly like `Select`, but it won’t raise any hydration errors since its ID is stable.

Comment: Worked for me on latest next/react installs

Answer (score 18):

Select component needs an instanceId, id mandatory
So Just add

**id="long-value-select"
instanceId="long-value-select"**

to your Select component it will remove the Warning :)

Answer (score 1):

Instanceid should be any string  in react select props it will definitely  work...

```
instanceId = "select-box"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select
  className={className}
  name={field.name}
  id="long-value-select"
  instanceId="long-value-select"
  value={getValue()}
  onChange={onChange}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  options={options}
  isMulti={isMulti}
/>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.